# i have a problem with prisma db pull when i want to the pull my postgres DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, prisma

The error message is:

> Error: Error in connector: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: Error querying the database: db error: ERROR: syntax error at
> or near "WITH ordinality"

my DATABASE_URL looks like this:
DATABASE_URL="postgresql://dbuser:dbpassword@host:5432/db_name?schema=public?connect_timeout=30&pool_timeout=30&socket_timeout=30"

what could be the solution to this error?

Comment: The database URL is irrelevant here. The actual SQL query that generated that error is important. Given the error message, I'd guess you are using an outdated (unsupported) Postgres version that simply didn't support `with ordinality`. Or your query uses it incorrectly. In any case we would need to see the query. Ideally include the exact Postgres version as well (`select version();`)  will tell you.

Comment: my postgresql version is 9.2.24

Comment: Postgres 9.2 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  and did not `with ordinality`. The feature was introduced in 9.4 (also no longer supported). Upgrade to a supported version (13, 14) and the error will go away.